# Navbar-toggle Button doesn't show collapsed elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to create a button that will reveal me the collapsed navigation links when the screen gets too small. The button does materialize, but I can't get it to perform anything besides appearing when the screen gets small.

The toggle button also creates small '>' arrows when I only intended to have the white "-" lines in the button.

I realized that jquery and bootstrap's js files should be included at the bottom of the body tag, but so far I've had no luck even with those added. Any help is appreciated.

https://codepen.io/Tintinator/pen/NvKRvO

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">

  <div class="container">

    <!-- BRAND, BUTTON -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-
      toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-nav">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="./newnewfoy.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- NAV LINKS -->
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navilinks">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Event</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Volunteer</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Sponsors</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="medialinks hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <a id="YOUcon" class = "mediacon" href="www.google.com"></a>
        <a id="IGcon" class = "mediacon" href="www.google.com"></a>
        <a id="TWTcon" class = "mediacon" href="www.google.com"></a>
        <a id="FBcon"  class="mediacon" href="www.google.com"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: your `<span>` tags have an additional `>` on the outside of them causing the arrow issue.

Comment: yikes. thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong data-target attribute and a css rule that limits nav height (50px) which doesn't let it to expand properly. And I believe parent element should be nav not div.

Try this instead:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">

  <div class="container">

    <!-- BRAND, BUTTON -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navilinks" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="./newnewfoy.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- NAV LINKS -->
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navilinks">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Event</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Volunteer</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Sponsors</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="medialinks hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <a id="YOUcon" class = "mediacon" href="www.google.com"></a>
        <a id="IGcon" class = "mediacon" href="www.google.com"></a>
        <a id="TWTcon" class = "mediacon" href="www.google.com"></a>
        <a id="FBcon"  class="mediacon" href="www.google.com"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</nav>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oevYvp

Comment: Could you explain to me why nav and not div?

Comment: <nav> is the semantic HTML5 element intended to be used for a main/primary navigation elements. Bootstrap docs also use nav not div. I'd say use nav if possible, but it should work with div as well

Comment: Could I also ask why you moved the "navilinks" id? My intention of putting the 'id="navilinks"' next to the unordered list was because I didn't want the navbar-toggle to show the medialinks div; however, it seems that putting the navilinks id in the div that encompasses the media links doesn't show them anyways.

Comment: Because Bootstrap expects you to use attributes in a specific way in order for their selectors to work properly, otherwise their css and javascript won't be able to 'find' certain elements and won't work as expected. You can check their docs for examples, you'll see that toggle button is expected to reference the parent div of collapsible navigation ul by id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is is, but did you add the plugin? (see image)

[image: bootstrap plugin info]

Comment: I added the jquery cdn and the boostrap.min.js cdn at the bottom of the body. I posted a codepen for the full implementation of what I'm trying to do

Comment: add "$(".collapse").collapse();" in your js file

Answer (score 0):

Within your codepen, I modified a couple lines of code and it seems to do the trick. I changed the data-target from a class to an id of #navbar and then updated the initial div in your "NAV LINKS" to include the id of #navbar. I forked your codepen for you. https://codepen.io/ckroll17/pen/qXWqbV

```
<!--           
      Changed button to data-target to #navbar
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-nav"> -->
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="./newnewfoy.png">
          </a>
        </div>

        <!-- NAV LINKS -->
        <!-- Added an id of navbar to the class directly below -->
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```